# Debugging a binary inside a snap

Tags: snap, chroot, debugging, strace

I am trying to run a binary that's from a snap through `strace` to debug its workings.

Because the executable is accessed via `/snap/bin/prog` which is symlinked to `/usr/bin/snap` I will only see snap's system calls, not the program's.

How can I go about running the binary?

I tried using chroot, but that tells me the binary does not exit:

```
$ sudo chroot /snap/prog/current /usr/bin/prog
chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/prog’: No such file or directory
```

Even though there is a binary at `/snap/prog/current/usr/bin/prog` that it could run.

Can I have a more direct access to the snap's execution?

NOTE: The same issue would arise if I wanted to run it through gdb instead of strace.

### UPDATE

I thought I had a good start when I found `--devmode` and `/var/lib/snapd/hostfs` but running a host bin just causes a segmentation violation.

```
$ sudo snap run --shell PROGNAME
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
# /var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/bin/strace                                    
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It seemed promising, but alas.

Comment: The simple answer to your question Can I have a more direct access to the snap's execution? is no. When you do some research you will see snaps are closed self contained systems.